# Should ALLUSERS property be specified in the .wxs file which produce Windows merge modules (*.msm)?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

We are developing a Windows Installer installer (MSI) using [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) 3.5, and we have used merge modules in our MSI.

In the MSI, we have specified ALLUSERS property value=1. Will the Windows merge modules (*.msm) use this property or should we also specify the ALLUSERS property in the .wxs file which produces *.msm files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's the [ALLUSERS property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Spelling and capitalization is critical.  Second, no, the MSI should set ALLUSERS=1 not the MSM.   This is an installer decision not a merge module concern.

If the components in the merge module require a per-machine installation you could consider scheduling an error custom action that enforces this.